# problemas con IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, autenticación, encriptación, web.config

Buen día comunidad:

Mi IIS 8.5 me está presentando algunos problemas que a continuación detallo:

1) Cuando encripto el web.config (AppSettings) con RSA el IIS 8.5 no levanta mi aplicación pero cuando el web.config está normal el IIS 8.5 levanta sin problema la aplicación. Como si no desencriptará la información del appsettings y no puede tomar los datos para la BD.

2) En mi web.config por defecto tiene el modo de autenticación en Windows pero en el IIS 8.5 en la opción de autenticación el tipo Anónimo sigue habilitado.

Por favor su ayuda.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema , para publicarla externa del server debes cambiar el pool a network services y darle permisos a la carpeta con ese perfil .

Answer (score 0):

Compañero resolvi el problema , en el punto 1 debes tener cuidado con la data source , si en la red posee DNS debes colocarle el nombre y no la ip del servidor de base de datos .En el punto 2 en el string de conexion debes dejarlo autentificacion true y tu base de datos debes crearle un usuario y contraseña y asginarle permisos a la base de datos . Ya que el problema nace cuando se autentifica con el usuario nativo de la sesion de windows , Cualquier consulta quedo a la orden.